# Macbook display blank after opening the lid

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

This has happened several times. The Macbook is connected to display with usb-c cable and after unplugging the cable I try to open the lid, the display appears blank and no matter what I do, it stays blank until restart.

Using OS Monterey on MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)

What kind of bug is this?

Comment: Can you clarify the sequence of events? When do you plug and unplug the cable, and when do you close and open the lid? What model of display?

Comment: @benwiggy The sequence is : unplug the power cable and the unplug display cable while the macbook is running and the lid is closed. When I open the lid to use the it, it is blank, no output in the display. Looks like bug in the OS

Comment: @benwiggy its 16" display but i doubt size got to do anything with it

Comment: I would love to know which type / grade of USB cable you use and the display. We have seen displays with multiple inputs miss the window for macOS to detect the display is connected on sleep / wake. With details - we might crowd source a fix.

Comment: @bmike, using 32" HP display and the cable I am not sure will check. It looks like a bug in MacOS, once usb is disconnected, the Macbook display should be lit automatically but with the sequence I mentioned, it never comes on.

Answer (score 0):

Unplugging a monitor while the computer was asleep or while it is still coming out of sleep/hibernation, can cause it to be screen-off until reboot.

While I don't have docs or related pages to point to, I can say that I experienced, and others said the same.  I think the reason is because it becomes confused about whether there is a display, and thinks that it should be sending its display data to the device that no longer us plugged in.

I never had a fix or workaround.  My impression is that it' sin the hardware-level, and cannot be fixed with an OS update.  Just don't do that.

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the problem that it still thinks display port is still connected so when the lid is opened, it remains blank. The workaround I do is I open the lid "before" unplugging the display cable, then unplug the cable while macbooks display is still there. In this way its not blank to start with. Shame that top of the line macbook still has same problems that was there 5 years ago!

Comment: I unplug the monitor while the computer is still running and yet still get the problem!

Comment: I think they'll make new machines rather than fix this in the old ones.  I assume it's hardware-level, and thus unfixable in the operating system

Comment: Usually this is due to the display / timing. We have many of these macs and unless we have a bad cable or a display that tries to “auto sense” which of many inputs is active - I can’t reproduce this. Are you certain your display is hard coded to the input chosen and the cable is good - there’s no other chatter on the USB-C bus on the display side?